# Force WasabiWallet to use system tor service

Tags: tor, wasabi-wallet

I am running Wasabi wallet on linux machine and would like to force it to use system tor service. Tor is being blocked by my ISP, but I have set up bridges for my system tor daemon, and it works OK. But Wasabi - does not.

It seems to me it starts it's own tor service and does not respects settings in system-wide `/etc/tor/torrc` config file.

Changing ISP or using VPN helps, but it is not the solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several important pieces of information mentioned [here](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/issues/8535#issuecomment-1181414044):

> - Wasabi Wallet 1 is distributed with a specific version of Tor binaries but WW1 actually works with *any version* of Tor running on given operating
>   system[^1].
> - Wasabi Wallet 2 is distributed with Tor binaries (i.e. Tor is bundled) and we actually always run the distributed Tor with [non-standard port
>   setting](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/blob/ae1f36185579347b4d2ea8ccf0429d478b9e472f/WalletWasabi/Tor/TorSettings.cs#L60)
>   to avoid using any non-bundled Tor versions.

So to explain it in simple terms: Wasabi Wallet 2 uses a bundled Tor because WW2 requires access to Tor control protocol and because it makes sure that the Tor version is reasonably up to date. So Wasabi Wallet 2 deliberately does not use system-wide Tor.

I can see potentially several ways how to fix your issue.

For people without programming skills:

- Open `$HOME/.walletwasabi/client/TorLogs.txt` file in a text editor and you should see a line `Configuration file "/var/tmp/dist/tor/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.` So maybe you can just modify this `torrc` file as you need.

For people with programming skills:

- Modify parameters passed to the Wasabi Tor by changing https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/blob/7201a57ddfce235a20815a76827ed378e318d169/WalletWasabi/Tor/TorSettings.cs#L96-L109 and [build](https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi#get-wasabi) the Wasabi wallet.
- Modify ports used by the Wasabi Wallet here https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/blob/7201a57ddfce235a20815a76827ed378e318d169/WalletWasabi/Tor/TorSettings.cs#L60-L63 to use your system-wide Tor (i.e. `9050` and `9051`). Make sure in your Wasabi Wallet settings that the option `Terminate Tor when Wasabi shuts down` is disabled but it's disabled by default. Also your linux user must have a permission to access Tor control port. So this is rather a theoretical option.

Comment: Great! The solution with adding custom config helped. The file was not present in that directory (and the directory also did not exist), so i just added a link to system `torrc` file like this: `ln -s /etc/tor/torrc`. Works perfect